# Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

Tags: java, r, cassandra, analytics, datastax

```
> cassdrv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",
+                 list.files("C://Users//VRavimurugan.GSIN//AppData//Roaming//RazorSQL//cassandra",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))
```

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358528/rjdbc-cassandra-error-in-jfindclassas-characterdriverclass1-class-no)) : class not found

Tried this , but no luck [RJDBC Cassandra -> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358528/rjdbc-cassandra-error-in-jfindclassas-characterdriverclass1-class-no)

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358528/rjdbc-cassandra-error-in-jfindclassas-characterdriverclass1-class-no) you linked to says to change the driver name to be

> "com.datastax.driver.jdbc.CassandraDriver"

if you are using the dependencies [listed in that answer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fwX0DqcWSTLUFqSEMxVFVWY2M/view), as opposed to the older dependencies [listed here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fwX0DqcWSTb0NlOVFXOTJvcGc/view).

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in this [apparently related issue](https://github.com/OHDSI/SqlRender/issues/9#issuecomment-67440026), a solution may be to remove the package, restart, and install it again.

In your case:

1. Restart R
2. In a clean session run the following command: `remove.packages("RJDBC")`
3. Restart R again
4. Re-install again the package with `install.packages("RJDBC")`

This should fix it. A similar procedure should work for other packages giving the same error message.