# how to read data from Cassandra (DBeaver) to R

Tags: r, cassandra, database-connection, rjdbc, dbeaver

I am using Cassandra CQL- system in DBeaver database tool. I want to connect this cassandra to R to read data. Unfortunately the connection takes more time (i waited for more than 2 hours) with `RCassandra` package. but it does not seem to get connected at all and still loading. Does anyone has any idea on this?

the code as follows:

```
library(RCassandra)
rc <- RC.connect(host ="********", port = 9042)
RC.login(rc, username = "*****", password = "******")
```

after this step `RC.login`, it is still loading for more than 2 hours.

I have also tried using `RJDBC` package like posted here : [How to read data from Cassandra with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994077/how-to-read-data-from-cassandra-with-r).

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver", 
            list.files("C:/Program Files/DBeaver/jre/lib",
                       pattern="jar$",full.names=T))
```

But this throws error

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

None of the answers are working for me from the above link.I am using latest R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) and New version of DBeaver : 4.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

For your first approach, which I am less familiar with, should you not have a line that sets the use of the connection?

such as:

```
library(RCassandra)
c <- RC.connect(host ="52.0.15.195", port = 9042)
RC.login(c, username = "*****", password = "******")
RC.use(c, "some_db")
```

Did you check logs that you are not getting some silent error while connecting?

For your second approach, your R program is not seeing a driver in a classpath for Java (JMV).

See [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358528/rjdbc-cassandra-error-in-jfindclassas-characterdriverclass1-class-no) for help how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Edmon. I found a way to connect using `RODBC` and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I know this is really old, but do you happen to have your solution using RODBC? I'm have a difficult time connecting to DBeaver as well.